# Can I travel outside of the US during my OPT, but with an expired visa?

Tags: f1-visas

I am currently in [OPT](http://www.uscis.gov/eir/visa-guide/f-1-opt-optional-practical-training/f-1-optional-practical-training-opt). I would like to know if I can travel outside the United States and hope to return by applying for a renewal of my F-1 student visa.

Comment: Why would you need to renew your visa?  Is it not multiple-entry?  Is it expired?  Will it expire before you plan to return to the US?

Comment: @phoog US student visas are typically issued with a 5 year validity, but can be shorter based on visa reciprocity. As indicated, it is also possible to remain in the US in certain circumstances after the visa expiration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you qualify for [automatic revalidation](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1218/~/automatic-revalidation-for-certain-temporary-visitors), you can make short visits of up to 30 days to Canada or Mexico and return, so long as you have your I-20 (and I-94, if you have a paper one).

If you go to another country, or you don't have an I-20 endorsed for travel by your school, you will not be able to return without a new visa.

After you apply for a new visa, you also won't be able to return until the visa application has been processed and you have received your new visa. You cannot return to the United States while your visa application is pending. You will need the I-20 to renew your visa, so get it before you leave the United States.

This is a brief summary of the complete rules, which you can find at the [ICE web site](http://www.ice.gov/sevis/travel).

Comment: That is some new piece of info and I thank you for it, but I don't see on the first link you provided, where it mentions Canada or Mexico. Also, is that even possible with an expired F-1 visa even though the I-20 and SEVIS are current?

Comment: Reading a little more on the link you provided led me to the answer. Thank you, Michael.